# How to serialize groovy traits with Gson

Tags: groovy, gson, traits

I got a class implementing a trait which i want to serialize:

```
package com.company.project.model.v2

import com.company.project.traits.v2.TOpeningTimes

class Gasstation extends Poi implements TOpeningTimes {

    String brand
    double diesel
    double e5
    double e10
}
```

the trait class is:

```
package com.company.project.traits.v2

import com.company.project.model.OpeningTime

trait TOpeningTimes {

    List<OpeningTime> openingTimes
    boolean isOpen

}
```

I use gjson to serialize objects. I added an adapter to serialize geometries from LTS, all works fine but since i use traits gjson serializes something like this:

```
{
    "brand":"AVIA Xpress", 
    "diesel":1.709, "e5":1.789,
    "e10":1.729,
    "com_company_project_traits_v2_TOpeningTimes__isOpen":true,
    "point": {
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[8.2379,48.9507],
        "crs": {
            "type":"name",
            "properties":{ 
                "name":"EPSG:4326"}
            }
        },
    "type":"GASSTATION",
    "address": {
        "city":"Berlin",
        "houseNumber":"1",
        "street":"Flixstreet"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make gson handle traits?
thx

I tried to serialize goovy traits and expected it works like serializing classes but it doesn't

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization#exclusionstrategy

Comment: Is the problem only the `com_company_project_traits_v2_TOpeningTimes__isOpen` field name? In that case you might be able to solve this with Gson's [`@SerializedName`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) or [`FieldNamingStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html). Though note that Gson's main focus is Java, so there might be other Groovy language features which are not well supported.

Comment: thanks, @SerializedName worked. havent found it in the gson documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gson Annotations worked!

```
package com.company.project.traits.v2

import com.company.project.model.OpeningTime

trait TOpeningTimes {


    @SerializedName("openingTimes")
    List<OpeningTime> openingTimes

    @SerializedName("isOpen")
    boolean isOpen

}
```